# Prevent double on.click event Javascript

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

i'm still new in using java script, i try to make trigger time when first input field get click, then the function trigger will active, the problem every time i click input field, the triggger always active again, i try using

`event.preventDefault();`

but it's didn't work, please help me where i do it wrong ?
this my code

```js
 $('#trigger').on("click", function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
        var timeleft = 1;
        var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){ document.getElementById('countdown').value = `${timeleft} seconds`;
            timeleft += 1;
        }, 1000);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="trigger" class="form-control" required>
    <input type="text" id="countdown" class="form-control" required>
```

edit : i try it like this, but its still haunt me if  is this the best method?

```js
 function myFunction() {
        var timeleft = 1;
        var downloadTimer = setInterval(function() {
            document.getElementById('countdown').value = `${timeleft} seconds`;
            timeleft += 1;
        }, 1000);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="trigger" onclick="myFunction(); this.onclick=null;" class=" form-control" required>
    <input type="text" id="countdown" class="form-control" required>
```

Comment: you could try changing  `$('#trigger').on` to `$('#trigger').one`. however, it will only trigger on your first click.

Comment: I think that
    ***document.getElementById('trigger').addEventListener("click", myFunction,{once:true})***
it's more readable but you soulution with the onclick=null it's ok

Comment: I think i will use your suggestion @Edoldin, it's suitable for me, thank's you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use focusout event of Textbox

```
$( "#trigger" )
  .focusout(function() {
   myFunction();
  });
```

and after focusout you can disable Textbox